# How can you get the camera to move in Blender along a path while not centered specifically at one location?

Tags: camera

[image]

Blender 2.79 question. I'm new to blender, and I made my camera follow the path of the camera according to a Youtube Tutorial, but the camera won't move automatically when I click the play button. What exactly am I doing wrong? Also, I just want the camera to move by the sticks like someone looking out of a window of a car.